# Add values from second array after array values?

Tags: php

There are similar questions however none quite tackes the problem.

```
Array('1','2','3')
Array('4','5','6')
```

Assuming they both have keys 0, 1, 2. Merging the two arrays doesn't allocate the second array values after the first's since it overwrites keys with the same name. Neither using an union array operator (+) works. And using array_push results in this:

```
Array('1','2','3',Array('4','5','6'))
```

How can the values from array2 be added after the ones from array1 maintaining their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$merged = array_merge(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array1 = array('1','2','3');
$array2 = array('4','5','6');
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ('1', '2', '3');
$b = ('4', '5', '6');

$c = array_merge($a, $b);

print_r($c);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

Of course you can't merge arrays if it has the same string keys, obviously these keys will be overwritten

Comment: The output is not in the way the OP wants

Comment: Because what he wants is impossible

Comment: I was wrong. It works. `array_merge(array(0, 1, 2), array(0, 1, 2))`. Downvoters - test before you vote!

Answer (score 0):

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array2);$i++) {
     $array1[] = $array2[$i];
}
```

would append $array1 with elements from $array2, ordered.